# Generate QR code email body with multiple lines using Python module pyqrcode

Tags: python, email, qr-code

I'm trying to generate a QR code that once scanned with a phone will open the email App with the "To:", "Subject:" and "Body:" already filled out. I'm using the pyqrcode module and everything works fine with the exception of having multiple lines in the email body.

I want the body to look like this:

line1

line2

Currently, they look like this:

line1 line2

Here's the code:

```
import pyqrcode

text = "mailto:john.doe@email.com?subject=mySubject&body=line1%0aline2"

image = pyqrcode.create(text)

fileNamePNG = "qrTest" + ".png"
image.png(fileNamePNG, scale=5)
```

I tried using %0a for line feed, %0d for carriage return, the combination of the two and no success. I also tried using the multi-line string format but same results.

I'm starting to think that maybe the Body cannot have multiple lines. I've done plenty of Google searches and so far no solution.

Has anyone come across this or know how to solve?

[Here's the QR I'm currently getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1BVI.png)

Answer (score 0):

After a TON of research this appears to be an iOS bug. THANKFULLY it's been fixed in a dev patch: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/9383355.

How long will this take to get to PR, who knows. BUT, it is "fixed".

A workaround, which is FAR from ideal, is to add `<html>` and `</html>` around the body content. This will process natural line breaks as well as `%0A`, new line. `%0D`, return, doesn't appear to work at all.

Working Example:

```
MATMSG:TO:will@iam.com;SUB:Check out these jams;
BODY:<html>Hi Will,%0AI thought you might like to see this.

Thanks!</html>;;
```

[image: QR code]

[image: Rendered Line Break]